# How to show Hard Disk icon on Desktop via Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, hard-drive

Is there a command in Terminal that allows you to show the Hard Disk as an icon on your Desktop?

I know the manual process of doing it, which is, Finder > Preferences... > General and check "Hard disks" under "Show these items on the desktop:", but I want to be able to apply this configuration through the command line.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I am confused. the question you are referring to is 4.5 years old. i read that answer and must have inadvertantly edited it.   Not meaning to.  i reasd that answer and tried it but it didn't work so in my original question i added that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show various drive icons on the desktop use the following commands in Terminal:

External hard drives:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder ShowExternalHardDrivesOnDesktop -bool true
```

Hard drives:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder ShowHardDrivesOnDesktop -bool true
```

Removable media:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder ShowRemovableMediaOnDesktop -bool true
```

(To complete all options available in the Finder preferences: mounted servers:)

```
defaults write com.apple.finder ShowMountedServersOnDesktop -bool true
```

Afterwards restart the Finder:

```
killall -HUP Finder
```

To disable showing the respective desktop icons simply replace *true* by *false*